# Output is wrongly formatted

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    char surname[30];
    char name[30], matricno[10];
    int A, B, C;
    FILE *file, *file1;
    /* Open an existing file */
    file = fopen("Broadsheett.txt","r");
    if(file == NULL){
        printf("Error: Unable to open a file");
    }
    file1 = fopen("newbroadsheet.txt", "w");
    fprintf(file1, "University of Nairaland\n");
    fprintf(file1, "Department of Programming\n");
    fprintf(file1, "================================\n");
    while (!feof(file)) {
        fscanf(file, "%s\t%s\t%d\t%d\n", &name, &matricno, &A, &B);
        fprintf(file1, "%s\t%s\t%d\t%d\n", name, matricno, A, B);
    }
}
```

The output file is not well formatted. I don't know where the enclosure came from.

[Output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3mD8.jpg)

Comment: Please copy paste the output instead of using an image. Also, correct your code. You have a couple of `wink`s in there.

Comment: Note that [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong) and your code is no exception.  You should check the return value from `fscanf()`; things can go haywire if you don't.  Don't use `&array` as an argument to `fscanf()` — use just `array` (or sometimes `&array[index]`).

Comment: You should show us a few lines of the input (5 would be ample) and the corresponding 'badly formatted output', explaining what you think should be different — so also describing the desired output.  This would help you creating an MCVE ([MCVE]).  We can help if you create an MCVE; we can't if you don't.  And don't post pictures of text (text inputs or text outputs); embed the text directly in the question.  Copy it in (making sure there are no tabs in it), then select it and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent it as text.

Comment: Oh, and report errors on standard error (`stderr`), and make sure that you don't use the file stream after reporting that you failed to open it, and do make sure that you close the file.

Answer (score 1):

Your input file apparently has a header:

```
Name MatricNo A B
```

On the first iteration, `fscanf` successfully reads string variables `name` and `matricno`; however, reading the numbers fails as it sees `A`. So it prints `name` and `matricno`, being values `Name` and `MaricNo` and prints the value of integes A and B, which were not initialized and so are garbage.

On the second iteration, `fscanf` continues where it left off and reads strings `A` and `B` (last part of the header) but again reading the integers fails. So it now prints `A` and `B` and again the unitialized values of variables A and B.

Now everything is synchronized again and it prints the rest out fine.

So you should have checked the return value of `fscanf`. Also, `while (feof))` is wrong as it tells you that a read operation *encountered EOF*. So it does not tell you whether there is something left in the file, which you assume `feof` does. Finally, passing an array to a function results in the compiler giving the address of the array to the function, so don't put `&` before `name` and `matricno` in the call to fscanf (the compiler apparently ignores it but may give a warning).

Comment: What do you suggest if while (feof)) has limitations?  I'm new to C

Comment: You can use `while(1) { if (fscanf(...)!=4 && feof(file)) break;` So if `fscanf` is unable to read _and now_ `feof` is true, exit the loop. Note that if `feof` is false, there was another error. But this example shows that `feof` rather tests a type of read error, namely "no more data in file", than that it tells you whether there is something left in the file (which it doesn't tell you).